# Merge [js] and [javascript] tags

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

The two tags [js](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/js) and [javascript](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) should be merged. "js" is just the short version of "javascript".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change from [js](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/js) to [javascript](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) is now complete.